# Authenticate app users from Azure Cloud database

Tags: android, android-studio, azure-mobile-services, android-authenticator

I am developing an application that requires user to login before using the application. The app would authenticate the user's email address from Azure database. I have worked with local database systems and know the working of database, but I am new to cloud database and haven't worked with cloud database yet. I wanna ask if there is a way to run some authenticating code at Azure database that would return true or false to the android app through internet after receiving credentials entered by the user. Or suggest me if there is any other better and efficient way of authenticating the user from Azure cloud database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you develop the mobile app, then Azure Mobile Apps should be a great option for you. Very simple still powerful development model, authentication included. Shortly, authentication using AMA looks like that:

1. You create the account of AMA
2. You set up the connection between the AMA account and Google (to establish the trust)
3. You download the sample code and play with that - authentication looks like a few lines of code
4. When user log into your app, he will be redirected to the authentication provider, then enters his credentials, then, after provider check, the auth token will be issued and returned to your app with some data about user.

So, no password or whatever is going to AMA, only the auth token.
If you want to create a custom database for the auth, then AMA can be the solution as well.

Comment: I have checked the links you provided....in fact the whole site [Microsoft Azure] (http://azure.microsoft.com), related to authentication/authorization about Android Mobile App service. But it only elaborates about authentication and when it comes to authorization only says that it should be done manually in App back end code.

Comment: Sorry, i am not sure i am following you. Could that help? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-service-side-authorization/ or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116465/azure-mobile-services-httpclient-authorization

Comment: This is close, but Azure Mobile Services is not recommended for new apps. The authentication overview is all correct though.

Comment: Since this was the accepted answer, could you please revise to use Azure Mobile Apps? Mobile Services will be deprecated in the next few months, and customers who use it will have to migrate to the new technology. Either way, if customers base their code on Mobile Services, they will not get any new product enhancements until they manually upgrade their code. This is clearly spelled out in the Azure docs.

Comment: @AlexandrBelotserkovskiy Thanks, but please change the main text to Mobile Apps (instead of Mobile Services) and link to these articles instead: [Authentication and Authorization in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-auth/) and [Add authentication to your Android app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users/). We don't want anyone to accidentally use the old service.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Azure Mobile Apps with the Authentication/Authorization feature. See [Authentication and Authorization in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-auth/) and [Add authentication to your Android app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-android-get-started-users/).

Note that Azure Mobile Apps is the new version of the service Azure Mobile Services. New projects should **not** use Azure Mobile Services, as it is the older technology and will not be getting new enhancements.

For the actual username and password store for your users, consider [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/) or use a third party provider like Facebok or Google authentication.

Comment: but there is no sample code available for Azure AD for Android mobile app, Azure websites say "Coming soon". If you know one, please give me.