# How do I secure Azure App Service end-point for MobileServiceClient in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I have an app that uses **Auth0** https://auth0.com/ as the login provider and can login through multiple providers - Facebook, LinkedIn, Google, MS and Apple. This all happens client-side and I get the id and access tokens from the relevant service. No errors.

My app then connects to Azure App Services using the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices API
I use this to create the connection to the service:

```
client = new MobileServiceClient(https://mycompany.azurewebsites.net);
```

The app can then sync data between the local SQLite db and my Azure SQL db.
This all WORKS, no errors.

PROBLEM - the endpoint https://mycompany.azurewebsites.net is set with anonymous access and is not secured.

I can enable App Service Authentication and implement something like this for most authentication services, passing in the already-received tokens from login:

```
task = Task.Run(async () => await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook, AccessToken));
user = task.Result;
```

This is fine for MS, Facebook and Google authentication BUT there is nothing in the API for LinkedIn or Apple.

*Apple certification requires and Apple login IF other provider login choices are also made available to the user.*

Question:
How can I secure the Azure App Service in Node.js to accept an app ID and or password or token that I can supply from the client side as a constant to simply allow generic but somewhat secure access to this URL: https://mycompany.azurewebsites.net and NOT have this set with anonymous access?
And NOT USE the limited App Service Authentication.

Can anyone please shed light on this?
This is a major block in final progress with the app.

I did come across this but need something Node.js AND Azure App Service specific.
[Azure Mobile Services, HttpClient, Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116465/azure-mobile-services-httpclient-authorization/60365126#60365126)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should easily be doable.

1. Update your service side so that it implements the authentication mechanism you need.
2. Create a DelegatingHandler that implements the authentication mechanism.
3. Re-do your connection creator as follows:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient(url, new MyDelegatingHandler());
```

A delegating handler might be as simple as this:

```
public class MyDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
  protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken token)
  {
    request.Headers.Add("X-Api-Key", "MyApiKey");
    return base.SendAsync(request, token);
  }
}
```

This just adds a header to every single request with the API key, which you would then check on the server side.  For Apple / LinkedIn / others, you might want to integrate those directly using an Authorization header in this way.  Basically, you store the authorization header "somewhere" in your client-side code, after having done the auth, then you use a delegating handler to add the authorization header.  On the server side, you can validate that authorization header in the normal way for an ASP.NET or Express app.